# Disabling screen switch off

Tags: android, flash-cs5

We have a large fleet of android devices (Archos 70, running android 2.2) that we develop apps for to be used in the live events market.

One big problem we encounter is users touching the power key and turning the screen off, which generally they cannot find the key to turn them back on.

Is there any way in our flash air app that we can capture this key press and discard it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

No, actually this is impossible. This functionality is a part of Android. If you press power button everything is disabled. Even if you have wakelocks in your application they are all released when a user presses the power button. And I think that Google do not want to add such type of wakelock to their system because buggy applications can in this case block the ability to disable screen.